# NuGet Enable Package Restore with TFS

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, nuget

I have enabled "Package Restore", into our builds, to which we have a nightly build to ensure everything builds correctly.

We are getting package errors on our build machine, but not on our local machines.

The error is:

```
nuget.targets (43): Unable to find version (2.5.1) Castle.Core
```

I would assume the version are package are irrelevant, but I've added for context.

Any thoughts?

Package Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="2.5.2" />
  <package id="FluentNHibernate" version="1.2.0.712" />
  <package id="Iesi.Collections" version="3.1.0.4000" />
  <package id="NHibernate" version="3.1.0.4000" />
  <package id="NHibernate.Castle" version="3.1.0.4000" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Can you post your packages.config?

Comment: @Stuart - What does the full `/v:diag` diagnostic output say about the error?

Answer (score 1):

Set the build log to output at a diagnostic level. This should show the error during the nuget portion of the build.

The switch is:

```
/verbosity:diag
```

You didn't say what you are using to initiate the CI, so I assume you know how to modify the invocation.

You can also try to run the nuget.targets file manually via msbuild from the command line. From the project folder try:

```
msbuild myproj.csproj /target:RestorePackages /v:diag
```

or

```
msbuild myproj.csproj /target:BuildPackages /v:diag
```

Comment: After some checking - it appears we're getting remote server errors..


"EXEC : warning : Unable to connect to the remote server [C:\Builds\2\Case System\Nightly Dev\Sources\Users\SAS\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CaseSystem\Src\Case.Data.SQL\Case.Data.csproj]"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the package sources you need for restoring are set and not disabled on the ci machine.

To list/add them :

```
nuget.exe sources <List|Add|Remove|Enable|Disable|Update> -Name [name] -Source [source]
```

This could also be a proxy issue, but it's less likely since support has been added in recent nuget.exe and it would ask for credentials.